# Center an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

i have a problem in my css, i cant seem to center my image, unless i use padding, i tried using flexbox, wit justify-content, and align items, but it wont work, i don't know what to do, no matter what it wont center, unless i use padding. Can somebody help?

here is the code so far:

```
img {
padding: inherit;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

[here is the outcome of the webapage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuYbQ.png)

Comment: `img {margin: auto; display: block}` is inherently all you should need to center any standard `block` element - make sure there are no `float`s declared.

Comment: Making it a `block` element is necessary before using `margin:auto`. `img` is inline by default.

Comment: True, technically a `replaced inline` element, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```css
img {
  padding: inherit;
  margin:auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Setting a width so you can sets the margin to `0 auto`

`img { width:<image_size> margin: 0 auto }`

Option 2: 
Use block display and set the margin to auto

`img { display: block; margin:auto; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to set the margin-right and marign-left to null.

```
img {
    padding: inherit;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuming all the answers:

If your image have the property **display block**, to center your image you will need to do the following:

```
img {
    display:block;
    width: 200px; // You need to add a fixed width
    height:auto // Optional but i recommend, in case of you need a proportional redimensioning
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

If your image "lives" free inside of your content, without display property, then you just need to center with the property **text-align:center**.

Example:

```
.center{
    text-align: center;
}

<p class="center">
    <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="Image Alt">
</p>
```

I hope it helps you.